# Using project "Asp.Net Core Web API" with SignalR using .Net 7.0 or higher, how to add a route to a signalR Hub?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2022, asp.net-core-signalr, hub

I try add signalR to a new ASP.NET Core Web API project created for .net 7.0.

I try to follow the sample found at: [GitHub AspNetCore.Docs/aspnetcore/signalr/](https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/tree/main/aspnetcore/signalr) Without success because they pass through a StartUp class which seems to be the old way to do the job.

Also, the sample use IApplicationBuilder instead of a WebApplication object as the template create for us for a new project in Visual Studio 2022.

So how to define a route for our hub?

Answer (score 1):

See doc: [Use hubs in SignalR for ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Use:

```
MapHub<youHub>("route");
```

Just for reference:

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.

            builder.Services.AddControllers();
            // Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
            builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
            builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

            //EO start:
            builder.Services.AddSignalR();
            builder.Services.AddDbContext<MicroReseauDbContext>();
            //EO end.

            AppGlobal.Instance.ShowErrorAction = (msg)=>throw new HttpRequestException($"Error occurs: {msg}");
            AppGlobal.Instance.ShowWarningAction = (msg) => throw new HttpRequestException($"Warning occurs: {msg}");

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseSwagger();
                app.UseSwaggerUI();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllers();

            //EO start:
            app.MapHub<LogHub>("Log/LogHub");
            //EO end.

            app.Run();
        }
    }
```